# MySQL - Getting the percentage of an occurrence

Tags: mysql, query

I'll do my best to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a table called "Actions" and in Actions I have a column called "Resolution". In resolution some the entries, as an example, are "Fail", "Pending", "Completed" and "Cancelled".

I am trying to write a query that will tell me what percentage of the entries are "Cancelled". I hope I've explained myself. I am fairly new to SQL so please bear with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the percentage you need to divide the sum of the value, with the total and multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

`resolution='Cancelled'` is an expression returning 0 for false, or 1 for true.

So:

```
SELECT SUM(resolution='Cancelled')*100/count(*)
FROM table
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7dd8beef9387293c8337fca08811cd82)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can I assume that "count" is the number of all the rows?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing me to fiddle!!!